# specifying preferred results for GROUP BY values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have the following (simplified) query:

```
SELECT
u.idnumber AS user_idnumber,
sst_status.value AS scorm_status,
sst_starttime.value AS scorm_starttime,
sst_duration.value AS scorm_duration,
sst_score.value AS scorm_score,
u.id as uid,
s.id as scormid,
ss.id as ssid

FROM {user} u

LEFT JOIN {prog_user_assignment} prua ON prua.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN {prog} pr ON prua.programid = pr.id
LEFT JOIN {prog_courseset} prcs ON prcs.programid = pr.id
LEFT JOIN {prog_courseset_course} prcsc ON prcsc.coursesetid = prcs.id
LEFT JOIN {course} c ON prcsc.courseid = c.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm} s ON s.id = cm.instance
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes} ss ON ss.scorm = s.id

LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_status
    ON sst_status.userid = u.id
    AND sst_status.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_status.element = 'cmi_core.lesson_status'
    AND sst_status.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_starttime
    ON sst_starttime.userid = u.id
    AND sst_starttime.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_starttime.element = 'x.start.time'
    AND sst_starttime.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_duration
    ON sst_duration.userid = u.id
    AND sst_duration.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_duration.element = 'cmi.core.total_time'
    AND sst_duration.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_score
    ON sst_score.userid = u.id
    AND sst_score.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_score.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
    AND sst_score.scoid = ss.id

WHERE u.id IN([SOME_EXAMPLE_IDS_HERE]) AND u.deleted = 0
group by u.idnumber, c.id
```

Now the problem is that without the GROUP BY clause, some of the records have values for scorm_status, scorm_starttime etc. However, these contain duplicates. But, with the group by statement, only NULL values are returned for these columns. Does anyone have a clue on how to resolve this?

Comment: One solution is to learn to use `GROUP BY` the ANSI standard way.

Comment: Since you are not using any aggregate functions, why not use the `DISTINCT` operation in your SELECT and remove the GROUP BY?

Comment: Agree with the above. To keep with standards you need to really grab the relevant values with a further join. But you can use GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX to get a single specified value if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX:-

```
SELECT
u.idnumber AS user_idnumber,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sst_status.value), ',', 1) AS scorm_status,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sst_starttime.value), ',', 1) AS scorm_starttime,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sst_duration.value), ',', 1) AS scorm_duration,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sst_score.value), ',', 1) AS scorm_score,
u.id as uid,
s.id as scormid,
ss.id as ssid

FROM {user} u

LEFT JOIN {prog_user_assignment} prua ON prua.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN {prog} pr ON prua.programid = pr.id
LEFT JOIN {prog_courseset} prcs ON prcs.programid = pr.id
LEFT JOIN {prog_courseset_course} prcsc ON prcsc.coursesetid = prcs.id
LEFT JOIN {course} c ON prcsc.courseid = c.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm} s ON s.id = cm.instance
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes} ss ON ss.scorm = s.id

LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_status
    ON sst_status.userid = u.id
    AND sst_status.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_status.element = 'cmi_core.lesson_status'
    AND sst_status.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_starttime
    ON sst_starttime.userid = u.id
    AND sst_starttime.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_starttime.element = 'x.start.time'
    AND sst_starttime.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_duration
    ON sst_duration.userid = u.id
    AND sst_duration.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_duration.element = 'cmi.core.total_time'
    AND sst_duration.scoid = ss.id
LEFT JOIN {scorm_scoes_track} sst_score
    ON sst_score.userid = u.id
    AND sst_score.scormid = ss.scorm
    AND sst_score.element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
    AND sst_score.scoid = ss.id

WHERE u.id IN([SOME_EXAMPLE_IDS_HERE]) AND u.deleted = 0
group by u.idnumber, c.id
```

This is getting the first non null values of these fields. Note that this is relying on the fields not containing commas (but easy enough to specify a different separator for the GROUP_CONCAT). You can specify an order for the GROUP_CONCAT to get your preferred value if required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simplified version of your query:

```
select u.idnumber AS user_idnumber, sst_status.value AS scorm_status,
       sst_starttime.value AS scorm_starttime, sst_duration.value AS scorm_duration,
       sst_score.value AS scorm_score, u.id as uid, s.id as scormid, ss.id as ssid
. . .
group by u.idnumber, c.id;
```

You will notice that most of the columns in the `select` are not in the `group by`.  This is using a (mis)feature of MySQL and would not generally be allowed in other databases.

What MySQL does is it chooses an *abritrary* value from one of the rows for the result.  The idea is that this works nicely if the column is constant for the `group`.  But, it doesn't usually work as expected in other circumstances.

If you want a non-NULL value, then you can use `max()` or `min()` to get the biggest or smallest value.

For instance:

```
min(sst_status.value) AS scorm_status
```

and so on.